# How does the data format between Angular's $http service and a Postman request (post requests) differ?

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing, postman

If by default angular content type is application/json, why do angular post requests not perform exactly the same as Postman post requests.

I do not believe this is a coors issue.

I can successfully make an http post request via Postman to a Java micro service.  Specifications chosen were: body: raw, content-type: JSON(application/json).  I send the request and I can log the data after parsing.

However, when I make same request via Angular or jQuery, the server is unable to parse the request, and the data I log is null.

```
var data = { longURL: longURLs}
// var data = JSON.stringify({ longURL: longURLs})

        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8081/shortlinks',
            method: "POST",
            data: data
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
                console.log(response)
        });
```

Both the object and object stringified work the same

I am using restexpress server side.  My endpoints are equipped to handle cross origin requests, Options request method, which return the appropriate responses that allow for the post request to proceed.  I was also able to bypass even the need for proper coors handling server side by adjusting angular defaults: `$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

I may have to dig deeper into different methods of parsing data server side, but I feel the simpler answer would be to first understand this difference...

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema relacionado y mi psot aquí http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609715/how-can-i-send-this-call-in-body-raw-in-angular-js-with- http-como-cartero . Are you solved the problem?

Comment: Lo siento, pero dejé de trabajar en ese proyecto, pero gracias por llegar